# Why does K-Medoids give different clusters while using the same data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cluster-analysis

What I want to do is create 3 clusters of coordinates based on the actual distance between the coordinates (in meters). I'm using the [pyclustering (v 0.9.3.1)](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering) library to create the clustering with the K-Medoids algorithm. I'm using this because it allows one to cluster based a custom distance matrix.

I have the following data (= `df` in code):

```
[[ 5.54234025 52.33171979] [ 5.63723058 52.30203804] [ 6.86358932 52.71470154] [ 5.65058518 52.56547845] [ 5.69671853 52.80095967] [ 5.78317201 52.3762015 ] [ 6.49274668 52.73134323] [ 6.8586198  52.83012204] [ 6.5078194  52.72374062] [ 5.7740027  52.36877315] [ 6.30996811 52.38282932] [ 6.15836758 52.73475669] [ 6.03619448 52.37375389] [ 6.17387631 52.45866285] [ 5.91738025 52.55758756] [ 6.34791259 52.3186396 ] [ 6.17001243 52.68707341] [ 6.27778913 52.23139991] [ 6.1405875  52.89187446] [ 5.63316393 52.33808183] [ 6.14512217 52.28988876] [ 6.95356307 52.77812292] [ 5.58405455 52.27015314] [ 6.15267544 52.2555669 ] [ 5.49667521 52.35360582] [ 6.20266605 52.70916272] [ 6.1387325  52.48840386] [ 6.09516641 52.51060003] [ 6.05012155 52.52538424] [ 5.70644521 52.54255734] [ 5.65057224 52.3641085 ] [ 6.08146155 52.4996728 ] [ 6.20260632 52.26755503] [ 6.05072828 52.51110921] [ 6.93545227 52.75212102] [ 6.15780868 52.25478387] [ 5.75571905 52.71123786] [ 5.52027589 52.3400946 ] [ 6.21963138 52.24181099] [ 6.16916039 52.24674126] [ 5.86227855 52.70830936] [ 6.93279755 52.75671467] [ 6.17937646 52.85055622] [ 6.27402919 52.38300518] [ 5.62067086 52.2992954 ] [ 6.41170455 52.52922947] [ 5.96875572 52.68304847] [ 5.7822089  52.37554773] [ 6.11871619 52.78736115] [ 6.63561409 52.56128167] [ 6.42255129 52.51588309] [ 6.92364237 52.77151984] [ 6.73894674 52.6465025 ] [ 5.64660587 52.358935  ] [ 6.84892799 52.70955256] [ 6.1904102  52.69754784] [ 6.89467815 52.78900327] [ 6.08559412 52.22708975] [ 6.55571008 52.62638016] [ 6.09647307 52.51267545] [ 6.05069507 52.51462529] [ 6.12719784 52.49278953] [ 5.91781415 52.55528909] [ 5.54622509 52.32510519] [ 6.27398416 52.68559986] [ 5.60932195 52.32223254] [ 5.50159906 52.35178719]]
```

And [this](https://pastebin.com/YCDZH9tC) is what the distance matrix (= `matrix` in code) looks like.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
df = create_data_set(data)

df_size = len(df)
initial_medoids = np.random.randint(df_size, size=number_of_clusters)

matrix = get_distance_matrix(data)


# create K-Medoids algorithm for processing distance matrix instead of points
kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(matrix, initial_medoids, data_type='distance_matrix')

# run cluster analysis and obtain results
kmedoids_instance.process()
clusters = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
medoids = kmedoids_instance.get_medoids()

# Display clusters.
visualizer = cluster_visualizer(1)
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, df.to_numpy(), 0)
visualizer.append_cluster(medoids, data=df.to_numpy(), marker='*', markersize=15)
visualizer.show()
```

This gives me different clusters every time:

[image]
[image]

Creating the clusters works fine. But the clusters are different every time. I noticed this has something to do with the fact that I randomly assign the three initial medoids. But I can't help but think that something has to be wrong. How can the end result be so connected to the random medoids you assign.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't notice any differences in these two figures,other than the centroids

Comment: The clusters are arranged differently, @ShubhamShaswat.

Comment: Isn't that it? The fact that you assign initial medoids? If you would have the same medoids every time the graph will always look the same. You can see here how having new medoids changes the clusters - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:K-Medoids_Clustering.gif

Comment: the cluster should be different every time,you initialized  with different medoids  and this the disadvantage of the algorithm,if you have more data then the clusters will be more similar even with the different initial medoids

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat is there a way to find the optimal initial medoids?

Comment: check out [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/k-means-what-are-some-good-ways-to-choose-an-efficient-set-of-initial-centroids) also, find out about DBSCAN which is more robust algorithm